# imagerotate function doesn't work

Tags: php, image, rotation, orientation

i have a problem with imagerotate(), after uploading image it's not in wright rotation, so i need it to rotate back, BD libary is enabled.
there is a function code

```html
function resample($jpgFile, $width, $newcopy, $orientation) {
// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($jpgFile);
$height = (int) (($width / $width_orig) * $height_orig);
// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image   = imagecreatefromjpeg($jpgFile);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
// Fix Orientation
switch($orientation) {
    case 3:
        $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 180, 0);
        break;
    case 6:
        $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, -90, 0);
        break;
    case 8:
        $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 90, 0);
        break;
}
// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, $newcopy, 90);
 echo "Rotated Image Copied to Destination.<BR>";}
```

image add code

```html
        $insert_image = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `".dbprefix."_gallery` (`user_id`,`title`,`description`,`image`,`views`, `date`,`category`) VALUES ('$userdata[id]','".$_POST['image_title']."', '".$_POST['image_description']."', '".$generate_name ."_".$generate_name_extra ."_".$_FILES['image_file']['name']."','0','".time()."','".$_POST['image_cat']."')");
        $select_last = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".dbprefix."_gallery` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
        $selected = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_last);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/gallery/".$generate_name ."_".$generate_name_extra ."_".$_FILES['image_file']['name']);
        $jpgFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/gallery/".$generate_name ."_".$generate_name_extra ."_".$_FILES['image_file']['name'];
        $exif = exif_read_data($jpgFile, 0, true);
        $ort = $exif['IFD0']['Orientation'];
        $width = $exif['IFD0']['ImageWidth'];
        $thumbnail = 'files/gallery/asd.jpeg';
        $success = $main->resample($jpgFile, $width, $thumbnail, $ort);
```

it's not uploading rotated image, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), you are simply ASSUMING that your `move_uploaded_file)` call succeeded, you are simply ASSUMING your DB calls succeeded, and you're simply ASSUMING that all of the gd operations succeeded as well.

Comment: sorry, my php si not so good, as i wanted to, could you help me with any examle?